# Как проверить корректность пути, по которому сохраняется файл

Tags: python, файловая-система

Мне нужно сохранить файл по какому-то пути `path`, который записан в переменную. Как проверить корректность этого `path`? Т.е., исключить в нём всякие con, запятые и т.д.

**UPD**: переменную path заполняет пользователь как сам того захочет. Исключить необходимо все невозможные в ОС Windows варианты пути к файлу (con, пустой путь, имя файла с символом ? и т.д.)

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста пример пути path, который записан в переменную и покажите что в переменной надо исключить.

Comment: @S.Nick дополнил

Comment: Не так-то и просто. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9532499/check-whether-a-path-is-valid-in-python-without-creating-a-file-at-the-paths-ta

Comment: Запятая же разрешена, вроде.

Comment: @Эникейщик да, точно, запятую можно